# Get data from google calendar using api in php

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am using **google-api-php-client library** to get data from my calendar it shows the **error**

> **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=my_key**

This is my code:

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php'); 

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar");
$client->setDeveloperKey('Zs4-y4qSHh8pDDtq7bnY5bdw'); 
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'primary';

$events = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId); 
$calTimeZone = $events->timeZone; 
date_default_timezone_set($calTimeZone);

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {


     $eventDateStr = $event->start->dateTime;
     if(empty($eventDateStr))
     {
         $eventDateStr = $event->start->date;
     }

     $temp_timezone = $event->start->timeZone;
     if (!empty($temp_timezone)) {
     $timezone = new DateTimeZone($temp_timezone);
 } else { $timezone = new DateTimeZone($calTimeZone);
     }

     $eventdate = new DateTime($eventDateStr,$timezone);
     $link = $event->htmlLink;
             $TZlink = $link . "&ctz=" . $calTimeZone;
     $newmonth = $eventdate->format("M");
     $newday = $eventdate->format("j");

    ?>
    <div class="event-container">
    <div class="eventDate">
    <span class="month"><?php

    echo $newmonth;

     ?></span><br />
    <span class="day"><?php

    echo $newday;

     ?></span><span class="dayTrail"></span>
</div>
<div class="eventBody">
    <a href="<?php echo $TZlink; ?>">

    <?php echo $event->summary;

    ?>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Did this just start happening? This could be because google calendar is suffering a very broad (world wide?) server outage.

Comment: Now it is working there was some issue with my library